# Why POST method is not working in mobile web application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, post

Currently I am working on mobile web application using Phone gap.. here, I am passing data between client (HTML page in mobile) and server (php in server) using GET method ... now everything is working fine but when i try to change it to POST it is not working.....!
what might be the problem..

**Client side :**

> `$.ajax({
>               url:'xxx?callback=?',
>               data:{userId:id},
>               dataType:'jsonp',
>               type:'POST',
>               success:function(output){
>               alert(output);  }});`

**Server side :**
I am using `$_POST['id'];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in the code. We can't see it though...

Comment: you need to post the code

Comment: It's not working with POST, ok. Then you'll need to check and see if any of your PHP contains `$_GET` and change it to `$_POST`. Do show your full code, PHP especially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-domain AJAX calls using **JSONP** works only with **GET**. JSONP works only for get requests as it uses javascript  tag for the request.
**JSONP** makes sense only when used with a script element. For each new **JSONP** request, the browser must add a new  element, or reuse an existing one

- Reference 1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP
- Reference 2: http://infoheap.com/jquery-jsonp-cross-domain-ajax/